# Почему зависает изображение ios симулятора на xcode 9.2-9.3

Tags: ios, xcode

После обновления xcode до версии 9.2 начал замечать зависания изображения в симуляторе. Особенно хорошо видно было при анимации интерфейса. Оказалось что проблема наблюдается не только в моем приложении, но и в стандартных приложениях симулятора, а так же на всех версиях ios(9-11).

https://youtu.be/px1LipIFSnY - демо проблемы.

Обновление до xcode 9.3.1 не помогло. Полная переустановка xcode, c удалением папок **/Applications/Xcode.app** и **~/Library/Developer/** тоже не помогла.

Память и цп при этом не загружены. И в целом мак не тормозит.

*MBP 2011. macOs 10.13.4, 16gb ram, ssd samsung.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогичная проблема наблюдалась на mac mini 2011 года и "отлипало" подольше.

С чем связано - вопрос, возможно из-за старых видеоускорителей, возможно преднамеренное "состаривание" устройств чтобы обновлялись. На форуме Apple также есть темы с подобной проблемой, причем началось это еще с беты, например:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/83570

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/97042

Возможное решение проблемы, прописать:

```
// С дискретной графикой
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 2
// Без дискретной графики
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 1
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я натыкался на эти треды. Но там многие пишут что у них в 9.1 все пофиксилось. С FramebufferEmulationHint 2 у меня муражки, c FramebufferEmulationHint 1 так же как и было раньше. А сами как исправили, новый мак купили?

Comment: Спасибо! FramebufferEmulationHint 2 - заработало со второго раза, теперь все отлично. Почему первый раз были муражки вместо изображения я без понятия, я просто установил сначала в 0, потом опять попробовал 2 и все магическим образом заработало.

Comment: @user2168735 , да, заменой мака. Миник даже на  "Hello, world" уже задумывался.

Comment: Спасибо, это единственное, что помогло. Но я установил поставил этот флаг
// Без дискретной графики
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 1
по-другому не помогало